# Could Far/NetBox use ssh-2?

Tags: ssh-keys, far-manager

When I'm trying to connect with shh key to a host without ssh-rsa supporting through Far (NetBox plugin) I got the error in the journal at the host:

```
userauth_pubkey: key type **ssh-rsa** not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
```

Using the same key in PuTTY or MobaXterm - connection is successful:

```
Accepted publickey for ... **ssh2: RSA** SHA256:...
```

Key was converted by WinSCP (and PuTTYGen)

Is it possible to use Far for the such hosts (f. ex. OLES9.1) with key authorization?

PS It is not allowed to add "PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa" on the host.

Comment: Which version of NetBox are you using?

Comment: NetBox of course supports SSH-2. But I assume you actually mean SHA-2. NetBox hasn't been updated for years. It does not support SHA-2.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, you are right, the issue is with the SHA-1 hash algorithm.  
NetBox 2.4.544.5  
I asked authors of the NetBox at github, this summer they promised to update plugin.

Comment: https://github.com/michaellukashov/Far-NetBox/issues/323#issuecomment-1773831064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, NetBox plugin was updated!
Latest version ([24.2.2.590] - 2024-02-20) supports sha-2.
https://nightly.link/michaellukashov/Far-NetBox/workflows/release/main?preview